# Show wait image/text while loading an ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, loading

I have a site there takes a long time to load so when the use click the button I want him to see a wait image before the site is ready to be showed I have tryed to put this in my .aspx file

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="pregLadingStatus" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true">
  <ProgressTemplate>
      <div id="overlay">
          <div id="modalprogress">
              <div id="theprogress">
                  <asp:Image ID="imgWaitIcon" runat="server ImageAlign=AbsMiddle" ImageUrl="/Wait.gif" />
                  Please wait...
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

but i cant get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout below links

http://www.dotnet-developer.de/2008/04/aspnet2005/display-please-wait-popup/
http://forums.asp.net/t/1121855.aspx/1